# how to configure dependencies in maven pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven-2

I am converting my simple working web application (runs from eclipse) to a maven project. This is my first maven project. I have 3 external jar dependencies to it and i added then to the pom.xml my build is failing saying that it can't find those 3 dependencies. here my pom.xml file

[image]
The build is saying that the 3 packages does not exist.

```
package javax.servlet does not exist
package org.apache.commons.codec.binary does not exist
package org.apache.commons.configuration does not exist
```

What i am missing? I am running my application from Mac and in the .m2/repository i see these 3 libraries/packages present.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to either remove the `dependencyManagement` tags that surround `dependencies` or add the `dependencies` again but nested within the `project` tag, i.e. at the same level as `dependencyManagement`.

[`dependencyManagement`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management) allows you to fix information about dependencies across a multi-module project - e.g. like version numbers - however you still need to provide a `dependencies` section alongside that so that Maven knows to include them.

If your project is not a multi-module project I would be tempted to not use a `dependencyManagement` section at all.

Comment: Thx this worked for me. One more thing, Do i need to have all those librarles in my local repository(.m2/repository). is their any alternative if i don't out them in my local. The reson i am asking this Question is i have read through some documentation that if we provide an URL maven will automatically pull in thoses libraries for us. Does this mean putting them in .m2/repository is an option

Comment: No, generally you won't ever need to. Maven will download the dependencies from the central repository for you.

Comment: So if i am understanding correct, i don't need to configure my pom.xml(like giving a url to central repository) to tell maven download the dependencies for the central repository

Comment: No that's right, maven knows about the central repository and your local repository automatically - they will be set as default values so there's no need to fill them in.

Answer (score 2):

**Just remove `dependecyManagement` tags**